# How do I remove all punctuation that follows a single word in Java?

Tags: java, string

I need to remove punctuation following a word. For example, `word?!` should be changed to `word` and `string:` should be changed to `string`.

Edit: The algorithm should only remove punctuation at the end of the String. Any punctuation within the String should stay. For instance, `doesn't;` should become `doesn't`.

Comment: Can punctuation marks can show up in other positions that are valid? Say, if you have a word ":test", does that mark stay or get replaced? Basically, are you removing all marks, or only at the end of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex to modify the string.

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("([a-z]+)[?:!.,;]*", "$1");
```

There are no "words" that I know of where `'` is at the end and it is used as a punctuation. So this regex will work for you.

Comment: The expression can be simplified if the string contains a single word and the intent is to remove *trailing* punctuation characters -- the OP didn't clarify, however...

Comment: bobbymcr I intended to remove only the trailing punctuation marks. How can the expression be simplified in this case?

Answer (score 6):

Use the method `replaceAll(...)` which accept a regular expression.

```
String s = "don't.  do' that! ";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\p{Punct}(\\s|$)", "$1$2");
System.out.println(s);
```