# How do I remove all punctuation that follows a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

It's for a game in which the user can input a value like "Iced tea.." 
I would like to manipulate the string to return "Iced tea" without the trailing punctuation marks.

Looking for most elegant / simplest python solution.

Tried

```
def last_character(word):
  if word.endswith('.' or ','):
      word = word[:-1]
  return word
```

which works if there's only one punctuation mark at the end. But it's not all-encompassing.

Found a [Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115679/how-do-i-remove-all-punctuation-that-follows-a-single-word-in-java):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("([a-z]+)[?:!.,;]*", "$1");
```

Comment: `word.endswith('.' or ',')` does not mean what you think it does.

Comment: It means that `'.' or ','` is evaluated to produce `'.'`, and that is passed to `word.endswith`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> 'words!?.,;:'.rstrip('?:!.,;')
'words'
```

Comment: So would the function be something like word = word.rstrip('?:!.,;') and then return word? I'm a newbie, apologies if this is really basic.

Comment: Or you could just return it directly.

Comment: What do you mean by return it directly?

Comment: `return word.rstrip('?:!.,;')`

Comment: Ahh, awesome! That simplifies things. Shall keep that in mind for the future. Thank you so much. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `rstrip` is probably what you want.  But in general, it's not hard to translate something like that Java into Python.  A direct translation would look like this:

```
import re
subject_string = 'Iced tea..'
result_string = re.sub('([a-z]+)[?:!.,;]*',r'\1',subject_string)
```

Comment: Good to know. But when I try it as follows: subject_string = word 
 result_string = re.sub('([a-z]+)[?:!.,;]*', r'\1', word)
I get the result "None"

Comment: you need to return result_string in that case, or just `return re.sub(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
s='aaa...,'
count= 0
>>> for l in s[::-1]:
...     if l in string.punctuation:
...             count = count +1
...     else:
...             break
>>> s[:c]
'aaa'
```